# $.getJSON() doesn't get json file from url

Tags: jquery, getjson

I am trying to print value by storing **key:value** in a JSON file .
And the JSON file is on a url **cdn.localhost**.

**Code :**

```
var jsonFile = "http://cdn.localhost/json/states.demo.json&jsoncallback=?";
                jQuery.getJSON(jsonFile, {format: 'json'}).done(function(data) {
                    jQuery.each(data, function(sKey, sVal) {
                         console.log(sValue);
                    });
```

But unfortunately the $.getJSON method fails to read the JSON file.

Is my code right? Kindly suggest me how to solve this problem.

Comment: That looks like a jsonp call, not json

Comment: What error do you get? @cfs - jQuery silently turns it into a JSONP request and hands the data off to the callback.

Comment: Also note you attempt to log sValue but in the function you name the variable sVal.

Comment: I get an error while trying to open that url.

Comment: @andrewb Sorry ! That was a typo. I have also modified that and got NO result.

Comment: @Adam The error is "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://cdn.localhost/json/states.demo.json&jsoncallback=jQuery17108244676899581436_1380021527414?format=json&_=1380021527519"

Comment: @Sam - then I think you found your problem.

Comment: Did you check your is correct or not by entering your url directly from browser if you see example http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#example-0 if I hit flickr url http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?&format=json I get json data check this first

Comment: To be sure, there are other things wrong with your code as well. You should be using `?jsoncallback=?`, not `&jsoncallback=?`. As well, as others have pointed out, you are logging `sValue` but you have no defined it anywhere and are probably meaning to log `sVal`. First things first, though - get the right URL.

Comment: @Adam - I have also tired  for "?jsoncallback=?" and got no solution.And I have tested the JSON url and getting the desired result.

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA Yes ! I have tested the url directly from browser and getting desired output.

Comment: @Sam - then why in the world did you say you are getting a 404 network error? Are you still seeing that error in your console when you are making the $.getJSON request?

Comment: @Adam Previously I was getting 404 but after removing "&jsoncallback=?" I am getting 200 without JSON response in firebug

Comment: Are you getting a text response in your network tab? Perhaps it's not actually a JSON string. Validate it by copying it and pasting it into jsonlint.com